# Qt Dialog "Show more information" button?

Tags: qt, button, windows-7

Is it possible for a QMessageBox to have one of those nifty arrow buttons,
that Windows 7 has to show more text in a dialog?
Eg:
The "details" button in this picture.
[image: Windows 7 Dialog with 'show more information (Details) button']

It could probably be made by a custom button and icon (or a clickable Qlabel),
but I'm wondering if there's a highly abstracted Qt function for it I haven't discovered,
which will deal with all the window resizing, transition, etc.

(I'm using python 2,7 and PyQt4, but I assume that any appropriate Qt function will be supported)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Windows 7 to test this, but you may want to try setDetailedText: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmessagebox.html#setDetailedText. On MacOS it does something similar.

Comment: I did try that, having similiar suspicions, but the button isn't the arrow 'drop down' button. It's a simple "view details..." button.

Answer (score -1):

Qt is cross platform, so It can't implement a button with a style, that only win7 support. But you can easily make button looks similar.

Comment: I can't understand this... Everything has a native style. Platform specific API is used on each platform: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.7/src/gui/styles.